# In a particular project (MVC5) I could not able to add view as well as in the existing razor view Intellsense is not working in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor-2

One of my project build in MVC5 where I need to modify in view, but in this project I could not able to add view by right click option ( both from view folder as well as from particular controller). I copied another existing view and rename it as per my requirement, but in that view Intelsence is not working.
 Can anyone suggest me any patch up missing anywhere?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe you are on 'Class View' instead of 'Solution Explorer'

Comment: Hi Jacob,
  I am confirmed I am in solution explorer

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your vs2012  [asp.net-mvc-5-vs2012](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/start-the-new-taste-of-visual-studio-2012-with-web-tools-201/)

- Visual Studio 2012 update 4
- Web Tools 2013.1